# return inside an if does work in mozilla firefox but stop execution in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ipad, css

I am working on Ipad App if i Click to **play historical time line** it works perfectly in mozila firefox but not in chrome. So i need to play it in chrome b/c after this it will work for Ipad too. Here is my code:

```
      <script>
       function test(){  //Test function is called onClick of time line.
       var ab=document.getElementById('test');
       move(ab.children[0]);
            }

        function move(elem) {
         var a=document.getElementById(elem);
         var left = 0;

      function frame() {

                  if(left ==0){
                  left= left+7;  // update parameters 
                  elem.style.left = left + '9px' // show frame 
              console.log(left); 

                   }
                  if (left == 7){
          elem.style.left = left + '5px';
          left= left+3; 
            document.getElementById('oregon').style.visibility='hidden';
       document.getElementById('south_dakota').style.visibility='hidden';

               $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#1st2006").fadeIn(600);

            });  

         console.log(left); 
         return;
                     }
          //this variable **left** goes up to value 100.
             if (left == 10){ 
          elem.style.left = left + '5px';
          left= left+3; 
                 alert(left);
         document.getElementById('all').style.visibility='hidden';

          $(document).ready(function(){  
           $("#1st2006").fadeOut(600); 
        $("#2nd2006").fadeIn(600);

             });  
         console.log(left);
            //In this Console nothing to be print in chrome and Stop execution.
              //but in firefox it prints actual value of variable left.
            return;
                    }

      </script>
```

Here's [a link](http://www.celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1//BrendonIPad_2/map/9-27-2013/#page_one)! working properly in firefox but not in chrome.

Comment: `return false;` maybe?!

Comment: @A.Wolff return false Not working too, i tried.